# confirmation about deleting a record from database

Tags: php, javascript

I am using php and javascript. I want to delete a record from database after a giving "Yes" and "No" confirmation to user. I am using confirmbox by google but don't know what should be my code structure inside that. I am new to programing. Can any one help me please

How can I add this php function on javascript

```
function deleteRecord($id)
{
  $sql = "DELETE FROM user_database WHERE user_id = ".$id;
  mysql_query($sql) or die("Can not delete");
}
```

And on page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
  alert("You pressed OK!");
  }
else
  {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_confirm()" value="Show a confirm box" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple yes/no confirmation dialogue with javascript :

```
<a href="job.php?do=delete&id=1" 
          onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record?');">Delete</a>
```

if user confirmed , you can precessed with your function to delete the record, else nothing going to happen in your phpside.

Comment: well yeah, but this is simplest approach, after he got the idea of how this is going to work, he can use more complex security fitted approach

Comment: I need to call a Javascript as I am using ajax. I got all confirm box with OK?Cancel but I want Yes/No option